# Insert all table in another table with different structure

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql and I have a table with the following
mysql> describe activities;

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| year       | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| month      | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| project_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| task_hour  | double(8,2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| from_otl   | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This gives me for a specific year, a specific month on a specific project for a specific user, the ammount of hours worked.

I will need to create a table with a different structure with data from this last table. This will have the same columns but instead of month and task hours, I will have each month as a column and the hours worked in this column.

Here is what I tried:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_a
(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
year INT(10),
project_id INT(10),
user_id INT(10),
jan_com double(8,2),
jan_otl tinyint(1),
feb_com double(8,2),
feb_otl tinyint(1),
mar_com double(8,2),
mar_otl tinyint(1),
apr_com double(8,2),
apr_otl tinyint(1),
may_com double(8,2),
may_otl tinyint(1),
jun_com double(8,2),
jun_otl tinyint(1),
jul_com double(8,2),
jul_otl tinyint(1),
aug_com double(8,2),
aug_otl tinyint(1),
sep_com double(8,2),
sep_otl tinyint(1),
oct_com double(8,2),
oct_otl tinyint(1),
nov_com double(8,2),
nov_otl tinyint(1),
dec_com double(8,2),
dec_otl tinyint(1)
);
ALTER TABLE `temp_a` ADD UNIQUE( `year`,`project_id`, `user_id`);
INSERT INTO temp_a (`year`,`project_id`,`user_id`) VALUES (SELECT `year`,`project_id`,`user_id` FROM `activities` group by `year`,`project_id`,`user_id`);
select * from temp_a;
```

But it doesn't accept the insert into ...

What I wanted to do is first fill in all the unique year, project_id, user_id into this temp table then update each record by going through the activities table and update the correct row with the value for the right month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `VALUES` when use `SELECT` in `INSERT INTO`

```
  INSERT INTO temp_a (`year`,`project_id`,`user_id`) 
    (SELECT `year`,`project_id`,`user_id` FROM `activities` group by `year`,`project_id`,`user_id`);
```

Comment: It tells me I have to wait 3 more minutes... I will definitely, thanks for the help.